# While running Function in selenium getting null pointer exception for fluent wait

Tags: java, selenium

The color if the button is `null`

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://toolsqa.com/automation-practice-switch-windows/");

    FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver);
    wait.pollingEvery(250,  TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    wait.withTimeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    Function<WebDriver, Boolean> function = new Function<WebDriver, Boolean>()
            {
                public Boolean apply(WebDriver arg0) {
                    WebElement element = arg0.findElement(By.id("colorVar"));
                    String color = element.getAttribute("color");
                    System.out.println("The color if the button is " + color);
                    if(color.equals("red"))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            };

    wait.until(function);
}
```

Comment: Getting following exception                                                The color if the button is null
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Function_Test$1.apply(Function_Test.java:30)
 at Function_Test$1.apply(Function_Test.java:1)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait$3.apply(FluentWait.java:207)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait$3.apply(FluentWait.java:1)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Flue

Comment: Don't call `color.equals()` when `color = null`

Comment: Comment is not for putting such a long information. Please edit your question to include it.

Comment: To the OP... in the future, make sure you put all relevant info in the question itself so that readers can more easily find all the info you provided. If you post your question and then remember something else you want to add, rather than post in the comments just edit your question and add it there. Thanks!